# Undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) when running script

Tags: ruby

When I run the following script to retrieve the first page of google results

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stackoverflow'))         

  doc.css('div.vsc').each do |element|
    puts element.at_css("h3.r a.l").content
  end
```

I get a `undefined method`content' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

How could I solve that? Or at least how could avoid it showing when executing?

Comment: It's working fine for me.. (Log In, Blog, Questions, Ask Question, Iphone, Careers)

Comment: But the way to hide it is to check to make sure you're calling the method on something non-null, rather than assuming `at_css` is returning something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dave Newton already pointed out in his comment, the result of `at_css("h3.r a.l")` is `nil` in your case. Neither the `NilClass` nor the object `nil` have a method `content`.

Workaround:

```
doc.css('div.vsc').each do |element|
  next unless elem = element.at_css("h3.r a.l")
  puts elem.content
end
```